# How to modify chapter title with titlesec?

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, chapters, titlesec

I would like to modify title chapter from vertical shape to horizontal with `:` based on  `titlesec` package within `book` class, for example:

```
                         CHAPTER 1:   INTRODUCTION
```

and make it appear in the Table of Contents with **bold** number as:

```
   CHAPTER1: INTRODUCTION                                      1
```

Moreover, I have problem with adding `:` in List of Figures as:

```
Figure 1.1:
```

The following code for vertical space between chapter number and chapter title:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
% chapters
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\filcenter\bfseries}
{\fontsize{20pt}{15pt}\selectfont\MakeTextUppercase{\chaptername{}\space
 \if@chapnumwords\formatchapnum{chapter}
 \else\thechapter\fi}}
{-1em}
{\begingroup\singlespacing\bfseries\fontsize{20pt}{15pt}\selectfont\MakeTextUppercase}
[\endgroup]

%\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{*-4.5}{*6}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{\baselineskip}
```

we implicitly get:

```
                              CHAPTER 1   
                            INTRODUCTION
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `block` style. This code should do what you want for   chapter headings:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\filcenter\bfseries\fontsize{20pt}{15pt}\selectfont}
{\MakeTextUppercase{\chaptername{}\space
 \if@chapnumwords\formatchapnum{chapter}
 \else\thechapter\fi}}
{1em}
{\begingroup\singlespacing\MakeTextUppercase}
[\endgroup]
```

As to the table of contents, you can do what  you want with the `titletoc` package.

Comment: @Work: I didn't test the code, as you didn't post a full compilable example.  The `begingroup .. \endgroup` construction is to limit the `singlepacing` directive  scope?

Comment: +1 , Many thanks. but give error with {\begingroup\singlespacing\MakeTextUppercase}
[\endgroup], so its replace by  {\begin{singlespace}\MakeUppercase}   
[\end{singlespace}]. Also,  give me error. do you have idea to fix it without replace with {}. thanks again.